# iPhone App gets Hang/Blocks the UI for few seconds while coming in foreground from background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, ios4

I have a very complex application which contains almost all UI parts. Now the problem is when I make my application in background and again comes in foreground, My **UI** gets **blocked/Hangs** for few seconds.

JFYI. This issue is on both Simulator as well as on Device.

Can anyone guide for this issue?? How to handle the app when coming in foreground??

Is it that my app contains so many UI parts and needs to reinitialize everything?? Or is there any iOS specific handling??

I have heard that iOS serializes and de-serializes the objects when going background and foreground. Please provide some guided links or so.. thanks

**EDIT :**

```
if(isInActive)
    {
        if([UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber != 0)
        {
            //User canceled the Notification alert but badge is still there which indicates that
            //the push notification had arrived...
            [self performSelector:@selector(handleNotification:) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0]; //change: From 2.0 to 1.0
        }

        isInActive = NO;

        int curTime = (int)ceil([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]);
        int storedTime;
        int timeDiff;
        storedTime = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"logOffDuration"];
        if(storedTime > 0)
        {
            timeDiff  = curTime - storedTime;
            int delay = [[LogOffMgr getInstance].LogOff.delay_ intValue]/1000;
            if(timeDiff > delay)
            {
                [[LogOffMgr getInstance] stop];
                [[LogOffMgr getInstance] LogOffTimer_tick];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have any server communication/Data downloading when come back to foreground?

Comment: This question is entirely dependent on what you are doing and the state of yoru app when going into background and coming into foreground.  Since that information is not available, all we can do is wildly (and probably inaccurately) speculate.

Comment: @Rupesh: for now i dont have any such server communication.

Comment: @borrrden: I guess you are right. But what i just want a general guidelines if you can provide. I would like to request others not to do any negative voting.

Comment: @DShah: Post your code here for what you do when application comes to foreground from background?

Comment: @ParthBhatt: Please see my code. in DidBecomeActive method. I am just handling my NSTimer in this.

Comment: @ParthBhatt: But What i have observe is when i keep nslog at the end of this method then it is executed soon after coming in foreground but then also my UI gets block. So what i think is it is not my code in that method creates problem but it's something that OS handles it.

Comment: @DShah: `[self performSelector:@selector(handleNotification:) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];`. This blocks your UI. So use `performSelectorInBackground` if possible.

Comment: @DShah: Did my answer help you? I have edited it a bit just now to give you a better explanation. Please refer to it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but from your code, I can only think

`[self performSelector:@selector(handleNotification:) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];`

may be blocking your UI. I think that it executes your `DidBecomeActive` method and then after a seconds delay it starts execution of `handleNotification`.  So use `performSelectorInBackground` if possible i.e. if you don't do any user interface related changes in `handleNotification:`.

`[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(handleNotification:) withObject:nil];`

Hope this helps.

Let me know if you need more help.